# Is there a simple word -> noun/verb/pronoun table?

Tags: parts-of-speech, dictionaries

I'm after a basic list of words and their "role" in language. It could be plain text, excel, csv, but all I want is, eg:

```
cat noun
run verb
```

etc. Simple as that. I'm teaching a young friend who's also a bit poor on the "parts of English" (as am I - I don't even know the collective noun for "nouns/verbs/adjectives etc") some basic programming, so we thought we'd make a simple Google spreadsheet lookup table language tester.

This is NOT a programming question - that part we can do, but having drawn many dead ends with either over-complicated web pages (ie: dictionary sites wrapped with adverts and extra html) or endless "hackers dictionaries" (just massive word-only lists) I wondered if anyone here had any ideas. Sorry if this is the wrong place, but it's called "English language" so I thought it might fit.

Thanks.

Comment: top 1000 words broken down by their part of speech: http://www.johnsesl.com/templates/vocab/1000words.php

Comment: Moby project's Word part-of-speech list: http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/mpos.html

Comment: Wikipedia on POS taggers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging

Comment: Are you familiar with WordNet? http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

Comment: @digitaltoast: According to our FAQ I think it *is* off-topic, but you've already got several useful pointers in comments, and even if your question gets closed, there's nothing to stop others adding more comments in the same vein.

Comment: Thanks all: @Hellion: Thanks for that - Moby's actual download file isn't available from that server, though I'm sure I can find it somewhere with a bit of digging tomorrow. Will reply if I find. If not, 1000words could work with a bit of copy and paste. john-lawler: Interesting link, will be useful. Nohat: No, I wasn't, but some of the data files the program install look very hopeful. FumbleFingers - fair enough, but as you note, the pointers have been good, and I only wish I could "rate up" some of the answers.

Comment: I only posted as a comment because I expect the question to be closed at some point.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have a lot of problems with this, simply because so many words aren't limited to a single part of speech.

Case in point:

`run - verb` - *Every morning, he would **run** down the street to **run** his business*.

`run - noun` - *After she went for a **run**, she tore a **run** in her stocking*.

Even **cat**, though almost always used as a noun, can be used as a verb.

Many other words have both verb and noun meanings as well:

> *man, pin, land, part, cap, test, strike, spark, dog, sentence*

Collectively, there are dozens of meanings to the words in that 10-word list.  (*Oh, add **list** to that list of words*!)  See?  It all depends how you word your sentence.

The word **mine** can be used as a noun, verb, or pronoun.

Bottom line: This seems like an unsolvable problem, especially if you plan to limit each word to a single part of speech.

Comment: that's a very good point, kind of makes me rethink the plan. Now I'm in a quandary - your answer was very good and helpful, but it wasn't technically an answer to the question. Community: What should I do here? Mark as answer, or go away and earn some rep so I can rate it up?

Comment: @digitaltoast: Your question as asked is off-topic for this site anyway. So you may as well accept this one. In essence, it suggests that your question is wrong, since you can noun verbs and verb nouns. (See what I did there?)